# Linear Regression & good sample?

Tags: regression, sample-size, statistical-power

Edited:
In relation with our research, the respondents were deaf employees but due to the difficulty to have a large sample size, we're hoping to target that the respondents will be n=40 to reasonably say that it is a good estimate of statistical inference of the data for prediction using a simple linear regression analysis. And so, how many should be the participants to say that it is a good sample to have a good prediction? -like to have a good correlation, from my knowledge, (is it true? that n= 30 is the smallest good sample size) then, what about for a simple linear regression?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is a hotly debated topic, and could depend on the underlying distribution of the variable you are trying to sample.

If the variable has an underlying  density with a tight, high peak and *never* any outliers, then a smaller sample size will likely be able to capture the characteristics of the variable in question. Think of a mean-zero Gaussian with very very low variance.  However, if you have a heavy-tailed distribution with low-probability, high-impact events, you will need lots more samples to capture that.  S&P500 day-over-day changes are an example of this.

[Here is a link](http://www.raosoft.com/samplesize.html) to a "sample size calculator," in which I do not have much confidence, as I have not tested it and I do not believe in formulas for calculating a sample size.  You may also want to look at [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/rules-of-thumb-for-minimum-sample-size-for-multiple-regression), which details many good answers to your question, some by analyzing $R^2$ values, some by rules-of-thumb, and other analytical means.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using R package, you can run a [power analysis](https://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html). Also the "30 size" method is an oversimplification of the [classical CLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT) and you [should not use it randomly](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29497/clt-and-stable-distributions).

Comment: I think "oversimplification" is too generous. No version of the CLT has anything to do with n=30. There's no mention of anything but $n\to\infty$ in any CLT.